# Questions regarding child marriage in islam

Tags: fiqh

I have some shubuhaat i need clarified.

Let’s begin with the age of Aisha (rah)

Honestly speaking I never had an issue with the age of Aisha (rah) , as I learnt that pretty early in my life; norms and customs differ from era to era so that was not an issue. The way it was defend to me was that children matured earlier and we have sahih Hadith saying that Aisha (rah) hit puberty, in the Hadith it said A’Qil, I inquired about the word A’Qil to one of the brothers here and he went and asked people of knowledge and he told me that A’Qil is another term used for mental maturity.

So Aisha (Rah) was mature and she clearly knew what was happening to her and how she was now a wife of rasullallah saw.

However, I now found out that “maturity” is not a condition of marriage. I did some research and another brother told me that puberty/maturity doesn’t necessarily imply mensturation because other signs are there like the course growing of pubic hair, formation of the breasts etc.

And we also know that verse 65:4 allows girls who haven’t menstruated to marry and consummate; but that doesn’t necessarily mean she’s not mature as she could of had other signs of puberty or she has a condition for late menses.

And it was previously mentioned that intercourse can only take place of the girl is “able to”. But what about the girls A’Qil? Would she even be aware about the situation of marriage that she’s in? She might have the physique to handle intercourse but really my point is what the application here?

Number 1: the very fact that the young girl isn’t mature means that she’s unaware, and of the husband has sex with her and she doesn’t even know what’s happening, this just seems exploitative. Ibn Qudama mentioned in his mughni the girl is made to have sex at 9 if she has the physique. This just seems so counterintuitive to Islam and I’ll explain what I mean.

Number 2: Muslims defend early marriage because families need to produce a lot off springs to keep their family going given that the life span was short. For a prepubescent girl, bearing children is impossible but she’s “made” to have sex. This seems extremely exploitative.

Ok the reason why I said this seems counterintuitive is the fact that Islamic marriages are meant to be a union, when it comes to a man and a prepubescent child, how is a union even meant to be when one is clearly incompetent?

Next, I don’t understand how the Hanbali position got to the conclusion of age 9 being the age to consumate based off the age of Aisha (rah) alone. This view is the view of Imam ahmed and Ibn Qudama, Aisha (Rah) was able to consummate at age 9 because she was mature (this is how Muslims defend her marriage), but when you analyze the criteria for consummation of the madhab , maturity isn’t one of them, it’s simply just physique. Ibn Hazm, Kbn Al-Qayyim, Ibn Taymiyyah, and Ibn Shubrahuma we’re more skeptical of maturity being 9 and betrothals overall from my understanding.

Lastly, to seal the deal; I found out about the “option of puberty”, where the girl can continue to stay in the marriage upon reaching puberty. Before, my understanding was that the girl wouldn’t be able to consummate before puberty so she can just break off the betrothal once she hits puberty and doesn’t need to consummate if she thinks their incompatible.  However, as pointed out before, the husband can consummate before puberty, and since the wife is immature she wouldn’t have knowledge of what’s going on. And upon puberty she will finally have the A’Qil to understand what has been happening to her and she can then split up. This just seems like complete immoral action, you would literally be using a prepubescent girl who can’t consent for sex then she finds out and annuls the marriage. Maybe I’m understanding this completely wrong.

Some of the rulings of the madaahab also contradict sahih hadiths, like the one where a girl (prepubescent virgin) was upset about her betrothal and the prophet saw cut it off. The rulings of some maddhab state that she doesn’t have a choice to cut it off before she hits puberty.

So overall I’m just confused. It’s probably the case that my question arise from the misapplication or misunderstanding of Fiqh. Hopefully some here can clarify.

Comment: The idea that there is a sudden switch at any point, whether puberty or 18, where someone understands something or doesn't is fantastical and not real-life. People before puberty aren't brainless and people after puberty and people after 18 don't have full understanding. So, a situation like someone totally doesn't understand then one day she understands doesn't exist. At most, there can be a change of likings, and that happens in full adults as well.

Comment: Also, I have not heard of any option for someone who reaches maturity unless the marriage was to someone truly incompatible in tangible terms (like wealth, etc.).

Comment: There is no hadith about a prepubescent girl being upset about her marriage. There is one hadith about a woman (a full adult, no indication of her being prepubescent) who was married without her permission and the Prophet allowed her to choose, since an adult's permission is a condition of marriage.

Comment: Here is the thing, if a prepubescent girl is married off and she is "made" to have sex without her even being aware of what sex is, how is that not the least bit exploitative? Children arent even baligh for their sins yet, but they can be made to have sex? Can you clear these misconceptions?

Comment: I belive she can annul the contract at maturity, as the woman asked th eprophet to annul her marriage that she didnt like. So basically, a man can marry a sagirah, have sex with her, and she may dislike it. So when she FINALLY hits maturity, then only she can annul? That sounds super exploitative.

Comment: I'm come here in good faith, I'm not trying to argue; I'm trying to find the wisdom behind such rulings.